# AWS Config rule iam-policy-in-use remains non-compliant despite adding policies

Tags: aws-config

I'm facing an issue with the AWS Config rule iam-policy-in-use. According to the

[official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iam-policy-in-use.html)

, this rule checks whether only the IAM policies that are used to access a resource are attached to the IAM users or roles.

To address the non-compliance, I tried attaching the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSSupportAccess` policy to:

- An individual IAM user.
- An IAM group that has multiple users.
  Despite these changes, the iam-policy-in-use rule still reports a failure.

Are there specific steps or considerations I might be missing to make the account compliant with this rule?
How can I further troubleshoot or understand the reasons for the non-compliance?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you able to get the solution!!!